# serviceWorker is a unresovled variable in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, service-worker

when i try to write my service worker i get the error  unresolved variable

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js').then(function 
(registration) {
    console.log("SW reg", registration);

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("SW failed", err);

})

}
```

how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try [2017.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) - it's not an issue there, as it bundles Typescript stubs for most popular JavaScript APIs:

[image]